# what is daemonize? I can't understand it

Tags: linux, apache, daemon, busybox

I'm reading the helper page of busybox's httpd.

In the page, there is an description about option f.
"-f Don't daemonize"

But I can't understand what the "daemonize" means.

Could you explain what it is?

I searched it on google. But it can'help me.

And also I want to know what implementation httpd of busybox is.

Is it implemented with apache?

Comment: To give a brief overview :: Running any executable as daemon (if it supports it) means that it can be run continuously in Background and it will keep listening for incoming connections in case of httpd. Daemon processes can be configured to run at startup and have functionality to be stopped and started via sysctl, or systemd service unit. Please refer: https://www.javatpoint.com/linux-daemon

Comment: In addition to what @GauravPathak correctly summarized: this is in contrast to a service that is started from command line, so from an interactive shell, which keeps control over the process. With a daemonized process there is no controlling shell that has direct control (can stop the process). Instead you need a framework to control such daemons.

Comment: "**what implementation httpd of busybox is.*" -- It is Busybox's own minimal implementation of an [HTTP server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_HTTP_server). Whereas Apache is a full-featured web server. See the charts in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_server_software

Answer (score 2):

The -f option for the httpd program in busybox allows you to run the program in the foreground instead of daemonizing it. When the -f option is specified, httpd will not fork itself into the background as a daemon and will instead run in the foreground, allowing you to see its output and any error messages directly in the terminal.

It is not based on the Apache HTTP Server, but rather is a standalone implementation of an HTTP server designed specifically for busybox.